# How to edit the html page and save it at the same page using Django?

Tags: python, django, backend

I have HTML page that contains a title and content that title, I had created an edit link that directs me to another page that should let me update the title and the content, and after editing click a button to save that update.

How i can let the user do this kind of updating using Django?

this is my HTML page

```
<h1>CSS</h1>

<p>CSS is a language that can be used to add style to an HTML page.</p>
<ul>
    <li><a href="{% url 'wiki:edit' %}">Edit</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can't your users do it the same way you are doing it or what

Comment: and also, your description is not concise enough please provide your views as well as your models and urls.py file

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this would be to use [Django template language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/language/).

You will have to store the title and content in a variable somewhere. Then, your `edit` page should update these variables when the user wants to update them.

If you use a template for your HTML, then you can simply use the value of this variable in the template, so that whenever the `edit` page changes something, it's automatically changed in this page.